# Adding addthis HTML to the dom after loading addthis script

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, popover, addthis

My goal is to have anchor tags where `href="#share"` and turn them into twitter bootstrap popovers with the add this buttons in it. I have this working. Something that complicates this is that I add the html to the document and the clone that i've tried `.clone(true)` but for some reason the events aren't following.

Here's the example: (click "share" button over image):
http://reggi.myshopify.com/products/change-it-tee

> **The problem** to be more specific is when you click the social icons nothing happens.

Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/reggi/5496545) of the below code. This is the require module I have that takes anything in the dom where `href="#share"` and turns it into a popover with the add this buttons in it.

```
define(["jquery", "jquery-bootstrap", "addthis"], function($, jb, at){

    var share = function(){

        var html = '<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->'+
            '<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_floating_style addthis_32x32_style hide">'+
            '<a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>'+
            '<a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>'+
            '<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share"></a>'+
            '<a class="addthis_button_tumblr"></a>'+
            '<a class="addthis_button_thefancy"></a>'+
            '<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<!-- AddThis Button END -->';

        var template = '<div class="popover fade top in" id="share">'+
            '<div class="arrow"></div>'+
            '<div class="popover-content"></div>'+
            '</div>';

        var isVisible = false;
        var clickedAway = true;

        $("body").append(html);

        var ignite = function(){
            var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=holstee';
            $("head").append(script);
            console.log("ignition");
        };

        $('[href="#share"]')
            .show()
            .popover({
                content: function(){
                    return $(".addthis_toolbox").clone().removeClass("hide");
                },
                html: true, 
                placement: "top",
                template: template,
                trigger: "manual"
            }).click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var toggle = ($(this).data('toggle') == undefined) ? true : $(this).data('toggle');
                clickedAway = false;
                if(toggle){
                    $(this).popover("show");
                    isVisible = true;
                    ignite();
                }else{
                    $(this).popover("hide");
                    isVisible = false;
                }
                $(this).data('toggle', !toggle);
            });
        /*
        $(document).click(function(e) {
            if(isVisible & clickedAway){
                $('[href="#share"]').popover('hide');
                isVisible = clickedAway = false
            }else{
                clickedAway = true
            }
        });
        */

    }



    return share;

});
```

Comment: Do you have a bootply or example of this anywhere pls? I would like to do something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call:

```
addthis.toolbox('.addthis_toolbox');
```

after you append the element to the popover.  That will trigger AddThis to render all the click events on the buttons.  I just tested this by calling the above from the dev tools console and all the buttons worked.

Comment: I can't wait to try this out! THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by loading the AddThis buttons after the popover has been shown. See the code below;

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-artist-add-share has-popover" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-content="<div id='pcontent'></div>">Share <i class="fa fa-share padding-left-20"></i>
</button>

<script language="JavaScript">
  $("[rel=popover]").popover({
    html: true
  });

  $("[rel=popover]").on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    $('#pcontent').html("<div class='addthis_sharing_toolbox'></div>")
    $.getScript("//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4fa624772af11b1b")
  });
</script>
```